# Not able to manage award flight via Manage bookings

Tags: air-travel, tickets, loyalty-programs, lufthansa

I had frequent flyer miles for Jet Airways and using those miles I booked an award flight with Lufthansa, which is a partner airline with Jet.

But I am not able to manage my flight on Lufthansa's website: when I provide my last name and PNR number, it cannot locate my flight.

I am wondering if there are any restriction on managing award flights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your PNR / booking code is *not* the same for Jetair and Lufthansa - if you check your booking at Jetair, it will show somewhere 'additional booking codes' or 'additional info', and there you will find the LH booking code. If they don't show it on the website, you might have to call them to get it.

Comment: Spot on...I got correct PNR by calling Jet airways